# strtotime display 01.01.1970 as result after new year change

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I'm using strtotime to display the date 'd.m.Y' for next week's tuesday to friday. 
In 2017 everything went fine, but since 2018 I get the 01.01.1970 as result. Can´t find the the problem. Here the code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$week = date('W');
$yearnow = date('Y');
$nextweek = date('W')+1;

$timestamp_tu = strtotime("{$yearnow}-W{$nextweek}-2");
$date_tu = date('d.m.Y', $timestamp_tu);
$timestamp_we = strtotime("{$yearnow}-W{$nextweek}-3");
$date_we = date('d.m.Y', $timestamp_we);
$timestamp_th = strtotime("{$yearnow}-W{$nextweek}-4");
$date_th = date('d.m.Y', $timestamp_th);
$timestamp_fr = strtotime("{$yearnow}-W{$nextweek}-5");
$date_fr = date('d.m.Y', $timestamp_fr);

?>
```

But if I use actual $week instead of $nextweek the shown date is correct.
Thank you.

Comment: PHP has better tools for working with dates. I suggest using them.

Comment: I'm not even sure how `strtotime("2018-W3-2") even works in the first place... ... and what @JohnConde said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve by this:

```
date('d.m.Y', strtotime('next week tuesday'));
date('d.m.Y', strtotime('next week wednesday'));
date('d.m.Y', strtotime('next week thurday'));
date('d.m.Y', strtotime('next week friday'));
```

Comment: Yes, have to change code:
$date_tuesday = date("d.m.Y", strtotime('tuesday', $next_week));

Comment: I have not thought about the code in the past because he did not generate an error until the error occurred now. Thanks guys for the help